# how can I handle this type with only one parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I have a model of these:

```
image: string;
redirect_option: 'PROFILE' | 'PRODUCT';
redirect: Product | User;
```

Now I render the list and want add a function:

```
const handleNavigateToRedirectedOption = ({ redirected_option, params }: { redirected_option: 'PROFILE' | 'PRODUCT'; redirect: Product | User;}) => {
    redirected_option === 'PROFILE' &&  navigation.navigate('UserProfile', params);
  };

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
 <Pressable onPress={}>
   <Text>List</Text>
 </Pressable>
);
```

Now I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'IProduct | CurrentUser' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CurrentUser'.
  Type 'IProduct' is missing the following properties from type 'CurrentUser': user_id, profile_image,
```

I know the problem but IDK how can I solve it. this comes at navigation...params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a syntax fix:

```
navigation.navigate('UserProfile', params as CurrentUser);
```

But yeah, the real problem might has something to do with the way you're structuring and typing your codes.